# ffmpeg to convert .avi, .mp4, .mp3, .flv, .mkv to mp4

Tags: linux, bash, unix, video, ffmpeg

I searching for a script that contains all of that attributes like the title.

I have done one simple but that is only for one attribute so far and i do not want one script for each of all attributes to not be confused.

Like this, running the script for like 10 minutes to see if there is any file that consist .flv and the automatic doing a convert for the file to a mp4 attribute.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Convert all flv to mp4
ext=.mp4
for file in *.flv; do
currmov=$file$ext
ffmpeg -r 15  -i $file  -b 296k -s 640x320 -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec aac $currmov
done
```

Thanks for help!
/M

Comment: Do the arguments to `ffmpeg` need to change for the other conversions?

Comment: Do you really want the output to be `file.flv.mp4`?

Comment: I want all files to be just .mp4 without the flv.mp4

Lets say the files name is movie.flv then i want the file to be just movie.mp4 instead.

Comment: Then you want `currmov=${file%.*}$ext`.

Comment: Ok next question, how can i build the script to handle all of the other attributes ?

Comment: @MikaelMezio they called "file extensions" and not attributes...

Comment: Why is this question not closed yet? Should be moved to superuser.com

Comment: @karlphillip It's not a great question, but it's still a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all extensions:

```
for file in *.{flv,avi,mp3,mkv}; do
        target="${file%.*}.mp4"
        [[ -f "$target" ]] && { echo "skipping $file - $target exists" ; continue; }
        echo ffmpeg -r 15  -i "$file"  -b 296k -s 640x320 -vcodec mpeg4 -acodec aac "$target"
done
```

remove the `echo` before `ffmpeg` if satisfied

Answer (score 0):

You just need a second loop

```
for ext in avi mp3 flv mk4; do
    for file in *.$ext; do
        ...
    done
done
```